# Visual Studio takes more than 20 seconds to load

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.3 to develop a project. There are over two hundred projects under one solution. Recently I've noticed that it takes twenty seconds each time I open this solution, which didn't exist before.

Is there something similar to an index in the database that can make Visual Studio load faster or other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is mentioned in the [Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.3#1735--visual-studio-2022-version-1735).

[image]

You only need to update Visual Studio 2022 to a version after 17.3.5